# How to have component interact with nested dialog component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a generic component. This component has N buttons, where N can be set by the parent. A parent component can have multiple instances of this generic component. When a button is clicked on the generic component, I need to notify the parent component that this button has been pressed, and some way to identify which button has been pressed. I then need to have that parent component be able to call some function on the nested component. Here's a really rough example of what i'm looking to do:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    ...
})
export class ParentComponent{
    public OnGenericComponentButtonPress(someId){
       if (someId === "foo"){
           genericComponentInstance.closeComponent();
       }else{
           doOtherThing();
       }
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'generic-component',
    ...
})
export class GenericComponent{
    public closeComponent(){}
}
```

I need some way to communicate back and forth like this. Assuming a parent component can have multiple instances of GenericComponent, is this possible?

Comment: you want parent-child communication ?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 communication forms:

1. Child to Parent
2. Parent to child

## Child to Parent

Communicating from the child to the parent can be done by adding [EventEmmiter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)  on the child and subscribing to the event on the parent.
Calling the parent is done by calling `emit` on the `EventEmitter`

Child component code:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-child',
   template: '<h2>{{myText}}</h2><button (click)="onClick()">do something</button>'
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  private myText = "Child Component";
  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public onClick() {
    this.clicked.emit();
  }
}
```

Parent component code:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from "./child.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Parent component</h1>
             <my-child (clicked)="doSomething()"></my-child>`,
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public doSomething() {
       do something...
    }
}
```

## Parent to Child

To call a child component we first need to get a reference to the component, this is done by using [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-var.html) if we have multiple components of the same type.

Parent component code:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList} from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from "./child.component";

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<h1>Parent component</h1>
            <my-child></my-child>`,
directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { 
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children:QueryList<ChildComponent>;

public callChild(){
    this.children.toArray()[0].doSomething();
}

}
```

**Example** in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7IqZxTWegIvsKEx5EO4j?p=preview)

**Note**: There are other ways to communicate between components such as using a common service.